# How to Change Permissions on an External Drive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, external-hdd

Newbie here.

I've got an external hard drive (EXT.4 format) that I'm trying to use as a destination for LuckyBackup.

It seems that I don't have permissions to use the hard drive.

I've tried to change permissions through 'Properties/Permissions' where it defines the user as 'root' and the group as 'root.' It also says that I am not the owner so I can't change the permissions.

I've also tried this solution: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/mount-a-external-hard-drive-with-execute-permissions/39767/4 but my 'directory' could not be recognized (even though the drive was mounted).

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible to change the permissions with `chown` (Change Owner) when paired with `sudo` (Super User Do): `sudo chown -R linda:linda /path/to/hard/drive`. Be sure to change the `linda:linda` to your user:group, and `/path/to/hard/drive` to the path of your external disk 

Comment: How do I find out what my 'user:group?' (I thought that it was $LINDA:$LINDA?) The drive in question - /dev/sdb1 - is mounted at:  /mnt/ata-WDC_WD2500JB-00REA0_WD-WMANK5969909-part1. Is this the 'path/to/hard/drive?' (I should mention that I'm using the latest version of Zorin.)

Comment: You can use `$USER:$USER` in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

**1. GUI tool: Disks**

The way to "take ownership" of an entire partition in the standard Ubuntu desktop is by using the utility "Disks".

- Open Disks
- Click the relevant drive in the left bar.
- In the right bar, click the relevant partition on the map so it has the accent color (will be by default if there is a single partition only)
- Click the cog wheel and select "Take ownership..." from the menu that appears.
  [image]

*Caveat*: This option may not be available in older versions of Disks.

**2. Using the terminal**

The `chown` command, to change ownership of the directory where the drive is mounted, works on any Linux desktop environment.

- Determine where the drive is mounted. You can do so from the output of `mount`:

  ```
   $ mount | grep /dev/
   /dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
   tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
   mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
   hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
   /dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
   /dev/sda1 on /media/vanadium/Files type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=8191,uhelper=udisks2)
  ```

  Entries starting with `/dev/` include physical partitions. In this example, there is a drive `/dev/sda1` mounted on `/media/vanadium/Files`, which is the single removable drive on this system. The mount point is `/media/vanadium/Files`.
  The mount point may also obtained from the utility "Disks". When clicking the partition, the "Contents" line indicates where it is mounted (if it is mounted).

- Changing the ownership is done using the `chown` command, in this example:

  ```
  sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/vanadium/Files
  ```

  *Note 1:* Add the `-R` option to do the change recursively, i.e., not only on the directory, but also on all files and directories in that directory, i.e., all files and directories on the disk. Be careful doing that: it is safe when all are personal data, but if you perform this command on a directory where also configuration files reside, changing ownership may cause problems.

  *Note 2:* `$USER` can be written as is: it is a shell variable that will be replaced by the login name of the user. You can replace it also by the actual login of your user, or any other user on the system.

Comment: I don't have a "Take ownership" option under the cog wheels in the 'Disks' utility. :( There is an option to 'Edit mount options,' though.

Comment: Strange. Perhaps an earlier version without this feature.

Comment: I tried the terminal command. Here is the output: linda@linda-Lenovo-IdeaPad-L340-15API:~$ sudo chown $linda:$linda /media/linda/external
[sudo] password for linda:            
chown: cannot access '/media/linda/external': No such file or directory
I'm using this external drive for Timeshift and LuckyBackup backups, so wouldn't -R cause problems?

Comment: The message says the directory `/media/linda/external` cannot be accessed, so your drive is mounted on another directory under /media/<yourlogin>'. Impossible for me to tell which.

Comment: Use the command `mount | grep /media` to see all drives mounted under /media. The path after "on" is the directory where the drive is mounted, i.e., the mount point.

Comment: Before I got your answer, I tried this: :~$ sudo chown -v linda:linda /mnt/ata-WDC_WD2500JB-00REA0_WD-WMANK5969909-part1
changed ownership of '/mnt/ata-WDC_WD2500JB-00REA0_WD-WMANK5969909-part1' from root:root to linda:linda. It seems to have worked. The problem seemed to be the /media/linda part of the path.

Comment: I changed ownership on another external drive and this time, the /media/linda/UUID pathway worked. As in: sudo chown -v linda:linda /media/linda/0fa28325-9261-4731-9673-11be12208bf2. In both cases, I opened the Disks Utility, right clicked on the drive I wanted to select, then read the 'contents' line for information about where the drive was mounted. That mount pathway is what I included, as in: sudo chown -v linda:linda /copy and past whatever mount pathway is listed in the 'contents' line of the drive you want to change ownership of.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else has been tearing their hair out trying to figure out how to change the ownership of an external hard drive from 'root' to 'user,' here's what I did:

Mount your external hard drive.

Open the Disk Utility, and right click on the drive you wish to select for ownership change.

You will see a 'Contents' line at the bottom of the screen, which includes the information 'Mounted at.'
This will give you the directory pathway you'll need to change ownership.
IMPORTANT: this pathway MAY or MAY NOT include /media/yourusername. Copy the pathway.

Open terminal. At the command prompt, type:

`sudo chown -v user:{user} {paste the pathway you copied from Disk Utility's 'contents' line}`

For me, this looked like:

`sudo chown -v linda:linda /mnt/ata-WDC_WD2500JB-00REA0_WD-WMANK5969909-part1`

(for my first external hard drive)
and:

`sudo chown -v linda:linda /media/linda/0fa28325-9261-4731-9673-11be12208bf2`

(for my second external hard drive).

I'm a humble newbie, not a programmer, but if these solutions work for you, great! Maybe a smart programmer will invent a tool to make it easier for us beginners to change ownership/grant permissions (hint, hint).

Comment: You can change `linda` to `$USER` and the system will use the user that issues the command Makes it more portable for others ;-) You are also missing a `-r` in there and could have done `sudo chown -r $USER:$USER /media/*` to set both and its contents to you. Oh and a q: why is one mounted in `linda` and the other not? ;)

Comment: Thanks, Rinzwind! I really appreciate all your help. I thought we were not supposed to use -R for backups? But I may have read that wrong. To answer your q - I have no idea why one is mounted in linda and the other is not. The one not mounted in linda is a very old drive. Could that be why?

Comment: my bad... /mnt is an internal disk the other external ... -r is  for recursive and has its uses and requires a bit of caution ... it can break things indeed