# Nautilus Warning

Tags: gnome, permissions, nautilus, dropbox

Newbie here.

I'm trying to use nautilus to change permissions on an external drive. I got this message: Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2019.02.14

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:12071): WARNING **: 09:05:07.134: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:12071): WARNING **: 09:05:07.134: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Nautilus-Share-Message: 09:05:08.022: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)

I'm hoping that someone can help me decipher this!

Answer (score 1):

Never use Nautilus as "root" only use it as your own user.

The clue is in your question:

```
/root/.gtk-bookmarks
```

- So user used is `root`
- Nautilus expects a hidden file `.gtk-bookmarks`
- The file will be at `/home/$USER.gtk-bookmarks` as that is the desktop user.

But these warnings you can ignore as they are intended for the maintainers of Nautilus. But it is not a good idea to use Nautilus as root: it -will- without warning change pernissions of files and a large amount of files depend on the user and group being your desktop user. Others need to be syslog, admin, cups and all with exact permissions set as is.

edit; to answer comments:

> I'm trying to use nautilus to change permissions on an external drive.

1 simple rule: admin tasks you do from command line. Has added benefit you quickly learn how Linux works: a lot of things are in a readable file that you can edit or have a tool to handle it.

When you add a new external drive the 1st time the system will mount it as root since the system wants you to identify yourself.

So to get access to an external disk you do 1 extra thing:

```
cd /media/linda/0fa28325-9261-4731-9673-11be12208bf2/
sudo chown -r $USER:$USER *
```

`sudo` will ask for a password allowing you to change owner and group

Next time the system already knows this and you only need to ask for permission to mount it. There is a file called `/etc/fstab` where you can add a disk/partition so it automatically recognizes this disk (each disk/partitions has a "unique" ID (UID) you can connect to and those look like your mount point `0fa28325-9261-4731-9673-11be12208bf2` ).

When mounting windows the same applies BUT the settings are set when mounting since Microsoft does not recognize Linux filesystems. So you mount it with a user and group (chmod/chown do not work).

Comment: Sounds like a good thing to stay away from. Any idea how I can change permissions on an external drive so I can save my backup files to it? I've used various 'chown' commands but the path to my hard drive is not recognized as a directory. I really like Linux but there has to be an easier way to get EXT.4 external drives to work when they've been automatically restricted to 'root.'

Comment: The question for the real problem, X, is here already: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424007/how-to-change-permissions-on-an-external-drive/1424032#1424032 Indeed, here, we see a user attempting a different approach, one that could break the system.

Comment: "Any idea how I can change permissions on an external drive so I can save my backup files to it?" depends on the drive... if windows formatted don't: again this will mess up permissions.  if linux formatted you use the normal `sudo chown` or `sudo chmod` with a `-r *` and with the permisions you want. BUT you should already have done that when you added it to the system. It goes hand in hand with adding to then alter permissions for it ;)

Comment: 'BUT you should already have done that when you added it to the system. It goes hand in hand with adding to then alter permissions for it ;) ' That's probably why I'm having these problems. When you say 'adding it to the system,' what exactly do you mean? I want to be ready for next time! :)